# Using non '.ts' / '.tsx' files in 'ts_library' as dependencies

Tags: typescript, bazel

I'm trying to import a json file from typescript (yes, I'm using the `resolveJsonModule` flag in my tsconfig). The issue is, I don't know how can I give this json file to `ts_library` (this is also valid for any other non `.ts` & `.tsx` files, like a `.env`). `ts_library` is always telling me that he cannot find my json file.

For example if I have this `ts_library` in a `BUILD.bazel`:

```
ts_library(
    name = "src",
    srcs = glob(["*.ts"]),
    deps = [
        "@npm//:node_modules",
    ]
)
```

with this `index.ts`:

```js
import test from './test.json';

console.log(test);
```

and this `test.json`:

```
{
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

it will throw me this:

```
index.ts:1:18 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './test.json'.
```

I think I need to somehow add the json file in the `deps` of my rule. But I don't know how to do it, because deps doesn't accept direct files like `//:test.json`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add files to the `ts_library` rule via the `data` attribute (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@bazel/typescript#data). This is where you can add the reference to the JSON file.

However, ts_library overrides the output module format, and `resolveJsonModule` can only be used with commonjs, amd, es2015 or esNext (ts_library overrides it to UMD)

```
Option '--resolveJsonModule' can only be specified when module code generation is 'commonjs', 'amd', 'es2015' or 'esNext'.
```

You can do this though if you use the typescript compiler directly via Bazel, rather than through ts_library:

```
load("@npm//typescript:index.bzl", "tsc")

srcs = glob(["*.ts"])
deps = ["@npm//@types/node"]
data = ["test.json"]

tsc(
    name = "src",
    data = srcs + deps + data,
    outs = [s.replace(".ts", ext) for ext in [".js", ".d.ts"] for s in srcs],
    args = [
        "--outDir",
        "$(RULEDIR)",
        "--lib",
        "es2017,dom",
        "--downlevelIteration",
        "--declaration",
        "--resolveJsonModule",
    ] + [
        "$(location %s)" % s
        for s in srcs
    ],
)
```

You can test that it works by using `nodejs_binary`:

```
load("@build_bazel_rules_nodejs//:index.bzl", "nodejs_binary")

nodejs_binary(
    name = "src_bin",
    data = [
        ":src",
    ] + data,
    entry_point = "//src:index.ts",
)
```

More information about this using `tsc` rather than `ts_library` here:
https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_nodejs/blob/master/packages/typescript/docs/install.md

Comment: Thanks you, that worked perfectly. The only thing I needed to add was the `--esModuleInterop` so `tsc` does not throw any error when building (I've made an edit to your answer). And sorry for the responding time!

Comment: The docs links doesn't work anymore, but is there a new alternative with `ts_project` ?